# How to execute list of functions from .c file using subprocess?

Tags: python, c, subprocess

I am parsing .c file in one software called Cariad tool which gives you detail about that file like:
list- functions
execute <function_name>
cyclic execute <function_name>
dump-status

I am performing this in command prompt right now. I wanted to execute function in python script.
The Script is:

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import call

cmd = [r'C:\Users\drb\Desktop\Cariad_Tool\SFA_v0.9\bin\Signalflussanalyse.exe',r'C:\Users\drb\Desktop\Cariad_Tool\Source_PDK2_ISP_255\mainEHR.c']
p1 = subprocess.Popen(cmd, cwd= r'C:\Users\drb\Desktop\Cariad_Tool\Source_PDK2_ISP_255', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
p1.stdin.write(b"list-functions\n exit\n")
p1.stdin.close()
output = p1.stdout.read()
```

And the output is:

```
b'[INFO] Parse function PsdEhr_GetQuality\n[INFO] Parse function PsdEhr_GetModuleVersion\n[INFO] Parse function PsdEhr_GetTreeChangeCount\n[INFO] Parse function PsdEhr_GetCurrentTimestamp\n[INFO] Parse function PsdEhr_GetAttribute\n[INFO] Parse function PsdEhr_GetNextAttribute\n[INFO] Parse function PsdEhr_GetSpeedLimit\n[INFO] Parse function PsdEhr_GetNextSpeedLimit\n[INFO] Parse function PsdEhr_GetChildSegment\n[INFO] Parse function PsdEhr_GetNextSibling\n[INFO] Parse function PsdEhr_Init\n[INFO] Parse function PsdEhr_SetProviderStatus\n[INFO] Parse function PsdEhr_ReportExternalError\n[INFO] Parse function PsdEhr_WatchdogCheck\n[INFO] Parse function PsdEhr_ProcessMessageCycle\n[INFO] Parse function PsdEhr_AcceptPsd04\n[INFO] Parse function PsdEhr_AcceptPsd05\n[INFO] Parse function PsdEhr_AcceptPsd06m00\n[INFO] Parse function PsdEhr_AcceptPsd06m01\n[INFO] Parse function PsdEhr_AcceptPsd06m02\n[INFO] Parse function PsdEhr_AcceptPsd06m03\n[INFO] Parse function PsdEhr_AcceptPsd06m04\n[INFO] Parse function PsdEhr_SetCurrentTimestamp\n[INFO] Parse function PsdEhr_DecodePsd04\n[INFO] Parse function PsdEhr_DecodePsd05\n[INFO] Parse function PsdEhr_DecodePsd06m00\n[INFO] Parse function PsdEhr_DecodePsd06m01\n[INFO] Parse function PsdEhr_DecodePsd06m02\n[INFO] Parse function PsdEhr_DecodePsd06m03\n[INFO] Parse function PsdEhr_DecodePsd06m04\n[INFO] Parse function PsdEhr_DecodePsd06Multiplex\n[INFO] Parse function PsdEhr_GetLoadAttributePool\n[INFO] Parse function PsdEhr_GetLoadSpeedLimitPool\n[INFO] Parse function PsdEhr_GetLoadSegments\n[INFO] Parse function PsdEhr_GetTreeConfiguration\n[INFO] Parse function PsdEhr_GetRootSegment\n[INFO] Parse function PsdEhr_GetPositionData\n[INFO] Parse function PsdEhr_GetSegmentData\n[INFO] Parse function PsdEhr_GetSpeedLimitData\n[INFO] Parse function PsdEhr_GetAttributeData\n[INFO] Parse function PsdEhr_GetSystemData\n[INFO] Parse function PsdEhr_GetGpsData\n[INFO] Parse function PsdEhr_GetRootTreeStateAttributeValue\n[INFO] Parse function PsdEhr_GetRootTreeStateSpeedLimitIndex\n[INFO] Parse function PsdEhr_GetChildrenCount\n[INFO] Parse function EHR_PSD_exec\n[INFO] Parse function Ehr_Access\n[INFO] Parse function EHR_init\n[INFO] Parse function mainEHR\n[INFO] Finished parsing all functions\n\n\nFolgende Befehle k\xc3\xb6nnen verwendet werden:\n\nlist-functions\n  Listet alle Funktionen auf, die analysiert werden k\xc3\xb6nnen.\n\nexecute <function-name>\n  Analysiert die angegebene Funktion.\n\ncyclic-execute <function-name>\n  Analysiert die angegebene Funktion mit wiederholter Ausf\xc3\xbchrung (ben\xc3\xb6tigt z.B. f\xc3\xbcr Stateflow-Charts)\n\nwrite-results <file-name>\n  Schreibt die Ergebnisse im CSV-Format in die angegebene Datei.\n\ndump-status\n  Gibt den Status aller Variablen auf der Konsole aus\n\nreset\n  Setzt den Status aller Variablen sowie die Parameterkonfiguration zur\xc3\xbcck.\n\nexit\n  Beendet das Programm\n\n\nPsdEhr_GetQuality\nPsdEhr_GetModuleVersion\nPsdEhr_GetTreeChangeCount\nPsdEhr_GetCurrentTimestamp\nPsdEhr_GetAttribute\nPsdEhr_GetNextAttribute\nPsdEhr_GetSpeedLimit\nPsdEhr_GetNextSpeedLimit\nPsdEhr_GetChildSegment\nPsdEhr_GetNextSibling\nPsdEhr_Init\nPsdEhr_SetProviderStatus\nPsdEhr_ReportExternalError\nPsdEhr_WatchdogCheck\nPsdEhr_ProcessMessageCycle\nPsdEhr_AcceptPsd04\nPsdEhr_AcceptPsd05\nPsdEhr_AcceptPsd06m00\nPsdEhr_AcceptPsd06m01\nPsdEhr_AcceptPsd06m02\nPsdEhr_AcceptPsd06m03\nPsdEhr_AcceptPsd06m04\nPsdEhr_SetCurrentTimestamp\nPsdEhr_DecodePsd04\nPsdEhr_DecodePsd05\nPsdEhr_DecodePsd06m00\nPsdEhr_DecodePsd06m01\nPsdEhr_DecodePsd06m02\nPsdEhr_DecodePsd06m03\nPsdEhr_DecodePsd06m04\nPsdEhr_DecodePsd06Multiplex\nPsdEhr_GetLoadAttributePool\nPsdEhr_GetLoadSpeedLimitPool\nPsdEhr_GetLoadSegments\nPsdEhr_GetTreeConfiguration\nPsdEhr_GetRootSegment\nPsdEhr_GetPositionData\nPsdEhr_GetSegmentData\nPsdEhr_GetSpeedLimitData\nPsdEhr_GetAttributeData\nPsdEhr_GetSystemData\nPsdEhr_GetGpsData\nPsdEhr_GetRootTreeStateAttributeValue\nPsdEhr_GetRootTreeStateSpeedLimitIndex\nPsdEhr_GetChildrenCount\nEHR_PSD_exec\nEhr_Access\nEHR_init\nmainEHR\n\n'
```

In this, there are list of function available in that file. I want execute all this function using subprocess. But I am not sure how to do it.
Please guide me.

Comment: Is that file compiled as a DLL with exported functions? Otherwise you won't get far

Comment: The Python interpreter cannot execute C source code.